# Descompactação de caracteres

Tags: c, bits

Estou tendo dificuldade no seguinte exercício

> Usando o operador de deslocamento à direita, o operador AND sobre bits e uma máscara, escreva uma função chamada descompactaCaracteres que receba o inteiro
>   unsigned e o descompacte em dois caracteres a partir de um inteiro unsigned, combine o inteiro unsigned com a mascara 65280 (00000000 00000000 11111111 00000000) e desloque o resultado em bits para a direita.Atribua o valor resultante a uma váriavel char. Depois, combine o inteiro unsigned com a máscara 255 (00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111). Atribua o resultado a outra variável char.
>   O programa deverá imprimir o inteiro unsigned em bits antes que ele seja descompactado e depois imprimir os caracteres em bits para confirmar que foram descompactado corretamente.
>   :

O primeiro caractere eu consigo descompactar, mas o segundo nao fica com o valor correto (fica o mesmo valor do primeiro caractere descompactado).

Logo abaixo coloquei as funcoes que estou utilizando para tentar resolver o exercicio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void compactaCaracteres(char a,char b);
void descompactaCaracteres(unsigned valor);
void mostrarBits(unsigned valor);

int main(void){
   char var1,var2;

   printf("Digite um caractere:");
   scanf("%c",&var1);

   setbuf(stdin,NULL);

   printf("Digite um caractere:");
   scanf("%c",&var2);

   compactaCaracteres(var1,var2);
   return 0;
 }


 void compactaCaracteres(char a,char b){
   unsigned compacta = a;
   compacta <<= 8;
   compacta |= b;
   descompactaCaracteres(compacta);
}


 void descompactaCaracteres(unsigned valor){
   mostrarBits(valor);

   valor &= 65280;
   valor >>= 8;

   char a = valor;
   mostrarBits(a);

   char b = valor & 255;
   mostrarBits(b);
}

// Função utilizada para imprimir os bits

void mostrarBits(unsigned valor){
  unsigned contador;
  unsigned mascara = 1 << 31;

  printf("%10u = ",valor);

  for(contador = 1 ; contador <= 32; contador++){
    putchar(valor & mascara ? '1' : '0');
    valor <<= 1;

    if(contador % 8 == 0){
        putchar(' ');
    }
  }

  putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que no inicio da descompactação o valor é perdido no primeiro `and` binário que é feito:

```
void descompactaCaracteres(unsigned valor){
    mostrarBits(valor);

    valor &= 65280; // aqui
    valor >>= 8;
```

Ao fazer `valor &= 65280` ou até `valor = valor & 65280;` fica apenas com o segundo bloco de 8 bit's e o mais à direita perde-se.

A forma correta de fazer a descompactação seria apenas obter o resultado do `and` sem modificar a variavel `valor`, assim:

```
void descompactaCaracteres(unsigned valor) {
    mostrarBits(valor);

    char a = (valor & 65280) >> 8; //só obter sem alterar o valor
    mostrarBits(a);

    char b = valor & 255;
    mostrarBits(b);
}
```

Com esta alteração para a entrada `a` e `b` dá-lhe a seguinte saída:

```
Digite um caractere:Digite um caractere:     
     24930 = 00000000 00000000 01100001 01100010 
        97 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100001 
        98 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100010
```

No entanto, aproveito para mencionar que a ideia de funções é modularização e reutilização. Nesse sentido a função `compactaCaracteres` devia devolver o valor compactado, para permitir ser chamada em qualquer lugar e fazer o que quiser com o resultado:

```
unsigned compactaCaracteres(char a,char b) {
// ^---
    unsigned compacta = a;
    compacta <<= 8;
    compacta |= b;
    return compacta; //<---
}
```

E a função `descompactaCaracteres` também deve de alguma forma devolver o resultado. Como são dois valores a devolver uma solução simples seria passar dois ponteiros com os valores a serem devolvidos:

```
void descompactaCaracteres(unsigned valor, char *a, char *b) {
//                                              ^---------^--descompactados
    *a = (valor & 65280) >> 8;  //alterar o valor de a
    *b = valor & 255; //alterar o valor de b
}
```

No `main` agora chamaria assim:

```
int main(void) {
    char var1,var2;

    printf("Digite um caractere:");
    scanf("%c",&var1);

    setbuf(stdin,NULL);

    printf("Digite um caractere:");
    scanf("%c",&var2);

    unsigned compactado = compactaCaracteres(var1, var2); //compactar
    char a, b;
    descompactaCaracteres(compactado, &a, &b); //descompactar
    mostrarBits(a);
    mostrarBits(b);

    return 0;
}
```

As mascaras de bits também são muito comuns de se utilizar com `define` para facilitar. Por isso também poderia fazer duas que iria facilitar. Algo como:

```
#define ULITMOBYTE 255
#define PENULTIMOBYTE 65280
```

E utilizar nos locais apropriados.